# Problems with Pyplot

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

Whenever I use  Pyplot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I got this problem. It shouldn't be installed the right way

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/artist.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 39, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/_path.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___sincos_stret
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/_path.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/_path.so
```

any ideas on how to solve this problem.

Comment: How did you install `matplotlib`?  It looks like some (likely all) of the c-extensions did not compile/link correctly.

Comment: I used : easy_install -m matplotlib

Comment: Source: http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html

Comment: That is under the directions for how to _remove_ matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using MAC OSX 10.9? If not, it may be that you've installed the wrong version for your matplotlib. In my case, ScipySuperpack installed the wrong version for me although I followed precisely the instruction for Mac OSX 10.8.

If this is your problem, you may solve it through the steps below:

1. Download the older version of SpicySuperpack in zip format (in my case, through https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack/archive/10.8_final.zip#).
2. Uninstall the old matplolib by typing: pip uninstall matplotlib.
3. Unzip the downloaded ScipySuperpack, if it has not been unzipped yet.
4. Go to the ScipySuperpack folder and type: easy_install matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg (use a different file name if this is not the one included in your downloaded ScipySuperpack folder)

Note: If you are using virtualenv, just activate your virtual environment before doing the easy_install.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If pip uninstall/install doesn't work, you might even have to go deeper. Do you get the same error with other modules within matplotlib or other modules in general from Python?

My suggestion, as you are on OSX, is to use `homebrew` to manage the installation of Python and pip and then everything should work much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
```

You may even have to go further to do the same with numpy.

There is some important information regarding getting matplotlib running on OS-X [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#os-x-notes) most significantly:

### "Which python for OS X?

Apple ships with its own python, and many users have had trouble with it. There are several alternative versions of python that can be used. If it is feasible, we recommend that you use the enthought python distribution [EPD](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php) for OS X (which comes with matplotlib and much more). Also available is [MacPython](http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/Leopard) or the official OS X version from [python.org](http://www.python.org/download/).
"

Comment: Do you mean that pip failed - if so what was the error - or that it worked but didn't fix the problem?